# Как лучше сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Времени уже было половина пятого" - можно так сказать? А, если нет, то как лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Было уже полпятого**. Или: **Была уже половина пятого**. 
"*Времени уже было половина пятого*" - вариант наименее приемлемый, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 0):

Дкмаю, что **сказать** так можно. Для разговорной речи вполне допустимо.